# Embed a "live" statistic in webpage, similar to google maps location

Tags: dictionary, embed, live, review

I would like to embed a widget/source code that can enable me to display the "live" busiest activities of a location I wanted to share on my webpage, specifically for restaurant or cafe I sharing with.

[www.tinytanblog.me](http://www.tinytanblog.me)

for instance, I created my Google Write Review and the Read More Review column for visitors as part of the convenience for them to leave a review directly from their Google account, which is linked to my page.